# Sybase Query : how to get month from date

Tags: sybase

I have a specific scenario in a report where I want to get a month in specific format.

```
Input : 
Month : 2 Digit OR 1 Digit OR 0

Expectation:
If I pass 2 Digit : e.g. 10 o/p should be 10
If I pass 1 Digit : e.g. 1  o/p should be 01
If I pass 0       : e.g. 0  o/p should be blank

but I need help to when I pass 0 and I get Blank.

Please Help / Advice
AT
```

Comment: How does your query look like?

Comment: select isnull(rtrim(right('0' + isnull(convert(varchar(2), '12'), isnull('12', '  ')), 2)),null)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will work for you:

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN @month = 0 THEN ''
         ELSE RIGHT ('0' + @month, 2)
       END AS Month
```